# How to select separate columns in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, select, oledb

I have searched a lot but didn't find a question like what I have.

I am opening an excel sheet with an OleDB connection and want to select (unnamed) columns, but not an entire range. The columns I want to select are:

```
B, F, M, O-X
```

I have tried a lot of ways to format the select and the closest I come to a result that actually passes through is this:

```
"SELECT TOP " + this.maximumRows.ToString() + " * FROM [Sheet1$B:B], [Sheet1$F:F], [Sheet1$M:M], [Sheet1$O:X]"
```

However what i get out of that is this (commas separate cells):

```
Data , [Sheet1$F:F] , [Sheet1$M:M] , [Sheet1$O:X] , F2 , F3 , etc...
```

Can anyone tell me how to form the SELECT statement so it takes the actual data instead of the rest of the query?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather try something like  `SELECT TOP X F2, F6 from [Sheet1]` ?

Comment: Sadly that give me an error. i tried [B], B, Sheet1.B, [Sheet1].B, [Sheet1.B] and Sheet1.[B] but i keep getting the following error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: Did you try with [F1], [F2] ... ? This is how Excel columns are shown in Access when no field names are provided.

Comment: Sadly [F1] or F1 doesnt work either, still giving the same error. This it the base of my query: "SELECT F1 (or [F1] doesnt work either) FROM [Sheet1$]"

Comment: Strange ! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201231/excel-sort-columns-by-row-content  and... what if you remove the TOP clause ?

Comment: using `SELECT 1 As Col, F2 As Cont ...` just printed the strings Col and Cont. I used the TOP in previous tries where the DataAdapter did not stop retrieving rows